# Updating row in pandas dataframe using loc not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named output -

```
RAW_ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_TYPE       ENTITY_NAME        IS_MAIN
01-03-2017        TNRMATDT          01 03 2017         1
04-02-2017        TNRSTRTDT         04 02 2017         1
documents         TNRTYPE           SIGHT              1
documents         TNRDOCSBY         NOT FOUND          1
accept            TNRDTL            accept             1 
23                TNRDAYS           23                 1
```

print(df.dtypes())

```
RAW_ENTITY_NAME               object
ENTITY_TYPE                   object
ENTITY_NAME                   object
IS_MAIN                       object
```

Note - `ENTITY_TYPE = TNRTYPE`, `ENTITY_NAME = SIGHT` AND `IS_MAIN = 1` will only come once in the dataframe.

I want to update some values if ENTITY_TYPE is TNRTYPE, ENTITY_NAME = SIGHT AND IS_MAIN = 1.

```
temp = output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == 1) & (output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRTYPE'), 'ENTITY_NAME']
temp = temp.reset_index(drop=True)
temp = temp[0]
if (temp == 'SIGHT'):
   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRDOCSBY'), 'ENTITY_NAME'] = 'PAYMENT'

   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE'].isin(['TNRDTL'])),
                                   ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = 'NOT APPLICABLE'

   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE'].isin(['TNRDAYS'])),
                                   ['ENTITY_NAME']] = '0'

   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE'].isin(['TNRDAYS'])),
                                   ['RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''

   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE']=='TNRSTRTDT'),
                                   ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''

   output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE']=='TNRMATDT'),
                                   ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''
```

The final output is -

```
RAW_ENTITY_NAME   ENTITY_TYPE       ENTITY_NAME        IS_MAIN
    01-03-2017        TNRMATDT          01 03 2017         1
    04-02-2017        TNRSTRTDT         04 02 2017         1
    documents         TNRTYPE           SIGHT              1
    documents         TNRDOCSBY         PAYMENT            1
    NOT APPLICABLE    TNRDTL            NOT APPLICABLE     1 
                      TNRDAYS           0                  1
```

As you can see everything is getting updated except the first two rows , i.e. ENTITY_TYPE = TNRMATDT AND TNRSTRTDAT.

I want to know why the below code is not giving the desired results.

```
output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE']=='TNRSTRTDT'),
                                   ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''

output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (output['ENTITY_TYPE']=='TNRMATDT'),
                                       ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''
```

I would be happy if someone could findout the mistake I'm commiting or tell me any work around.

thanks a lot.

Comment: this is the second time you are asking this question, and still no one is unable to answer you since we do not know what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: It's strange that I run your code and get normal results. The `ENTITY_NAME` and `RAW_ENTITY_NAME` columns in first two rows  are `''`.

Comment: @giser_yugang - yeah I know that it's '', I want to keep it blank

Comment: @MadhurYadav - What is expected output? `The final output` ?

Comment: @Onyambu - I have clearly mentioned the details in the question itself, if you need any extra information then feel free to ask.

Comment: @jezrael - the ENTITY_NAME should be '' for ENTITY_TYPE = TNRMATDT and TNRSTRTDT

Comment: @MadhurYadav - For me ot working nice, get first 2 values filled by `"`

Comment: @MadhurYadav - I think I know what is problem - `IS_MAIN` values should be integers, so need compare by `1` not by `'1'`. I add comments to my answers for comapre by integers `temp = output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == 1) & 
#                  (output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRTYPE'), 'ENTITY_NAME']` and `#m1 = output['IS_MAIN'] == 1`

Comment: @MadhurYadav - All values? Not only values per conditions e.g. by `output['IS_MAIN'] == '1'`?

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, i deleted it, I take my words back, I was looking at wrong value. BTW, the issue is solved ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your solution working nice, I try rewrite it for better readable and not repeat same conditions:

```
temp = output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & 
                  (output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRTYPE'), 'ENTITY_NAME']

#if values in IS_MAIN are integers
#temp = output.loc[(output['IS_MAIN'] == 1) & 
#                  (output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRTYPE'), 'ENTITY_NAME']

if (temp.iat[0] == 'SIGHT'):
#more general working if not match condition
#if (next(iter(temp), 'not match') == 'SIGHT'):

    m1 = output['IS_MAIN'] == '1'
    #if values in IS_MAIN are integers
    #m1 = output['IS_MAIN'] == 1
    m2 = output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRDOCSBY'
    m3 = output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRDTL'
    m4 = output['ENTITY_TYPE'] == 'TNRDAYS'
    m5 = output['ENTITY_TYPE'].isin(['TNRMATDT','TNRSTRTDT'])

    output.loc[m1 & m2, 'ENTITY_NAME'] = 'PAYMENT'

    output.loc[m1 & m3, ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = 'NOT APPLICABLE'

    output.loc[m1 & m4, ['ENTITY_NAME']] = '0'
    output.loc[m1 & m4, ['RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''

    output.loc[m1 & m5, ['ENTITY_NAME', 'RAW_ENTITY_NAME']] = ''
```

---

```
print (output)
  RAW_ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_TYPE     ENTITY_NAME IS_MAIN
0                    TNRMATDT                       1
1                   TNRSTRTDT                       1
2       documents     TNRTYPE           SIGHT       1
3       documents   TNRDOCSBY         PAYMENT       1
4  NOT APPLICABLE      TNRDTL  NOT APPLICABLE       1
5                     TNRDAYS               0       1
```

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem. all you have to do is make the column IS_MAIN to be numeric

```
df['IS_MAIN'] = df['IS_MAIN'].astype(int)
```

This should make it work.

Comment: Thanks @jalazbe, I should've looked into this problem straight away, thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @MadhurYadav perfect you got your answer.